# Swagger configurations ignored

Tags: java, swagger

I tried to configure swagger with jersey and seeing the below warning. Any pointer on how to resolve this?

WARNING: A provider io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig will be ignored. 
Ma

This is my configuration

```
public static void initREST(int port, String[] packages) {
        URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://0.0.0.0").port(port).build();
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig()
                .register(new CORSFilter())
                .register(JacksonFeature.class);

        config.register(DocumentApi.class);
        config.register(ApiListingResource.class);
        config.register(SwaggerSerializers.class);


        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.2");
        beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
        beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8002");
        beanConfig.setBasePath("swaggerapi");

        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("ipos.hashgraph.rest");
        beanConfig.setPrettyPrint(true);
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
        config.register(beanConfig);

        for (String pkg : packages) {
            config.packages(pkg);
        }

        System.out.println("Attempting to start Grizzly on " + baseUri);
        GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(baseUri, config);

    }
```

Comment: were you following any example to configure swagger ?? Or can you explain how your tried to configure. This does not give enough information on what is causing the break.

Comment: okay, added the code. Is this enough?

Comment: Check if you find helpful jeejava.com/documenting-spring-rest-api-with-swagger-2

Comment: I am doing it without spring so it doesn't help much

Comment: There is this github page for setting up swagger in jersey https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/swagger-core-jersey-2.x-project-setup